# Wireshark http filter question

Tags: wireshark

Are the filters `http.host != ""` and `http.host` the same? The first one makes the filter text edit turn yellow (suggesting I may get undesirable results) whereas the second passes the syntax check fine. They seem to produce the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of the NOT (!=) operator in Wireshark comes with a caveat, as mentioned in the 
[documentation](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html)

> 6.4.4. A common mistake
>
> Warning! Using the != operator on combined expressions like: eth.addr,
>   ip.addr, tcp.port, udp.port and alike will probably not work as
>   expected!
>
> Often people use a filter string to display something like ip.addr ==
>   1.2.3.4 which will display all packets containing the IP address 1.2.3.4.
>
> Then they use ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 to see all packets not containing the
>   IP address 1.2.3.4 in it. Unfortunately, this does not do the
>   expected.
>
> Instead, that expression will even be true for packets where either
>   source or destination IP address equals 1.2.3.4. The reason for this,
>   is that the expression ip.addr != 1.2.3.4 must be read as "the packet
>   contains a field named ip.addr with a value different from 1.2.3.4".
>   As an IP datagram contains both a source and a destination address,
>   the expression will evaluate to true whenever at least one of the two
>   addresses differs from 1.2.3.4.
>
> If you want to filter out all packets containing IP datagrams to or
>   from IP address 1.2.3.4, then the correct filter is !(ip.addr ==
>   1.2.3.4) as it reads "show me all the packets for which it is not true that a field named ip.addr exists with a value of 1.2.3.4", or in
>   other words, "filter out all packets for which there are no
>   occurrences of a field named ip.addr with the value 1.2.3.4".

It might be that for your specific filter at hand, the current capture are displaying the same results, but it might give you a different result with a different capture

"http.host" means any packet which have HTTP hosts
"http.host != "" " means any packet which http.hosts isn't empty.

How will the second one react if you do not have http.host at all (ie: non-http traffic?)  you might want to check that

Comment: When capturing no http traffic there will most probably be not http.host header. Empty or otherwise.

Comment: Exactly, so if the goal is to filter for empty "http.host" header, having positive hits for non-http would give a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

*http.host* - show all packets where http.host is set

*http.host != ""* -show all packets is set and not an empty string